# How to fetch json/xml data using REGEX

Tags: json, linux, shell

I am new to regex and Linux, I want to know how we can fetch JSON/XML data using regex using a Linux terminal. I am a windows user so currently working on the windows subsystem for Linux. I know I should use jq for JSON but the requirement is to use regex, the pattern that I will have will be same in every report so regex can be used even though it is not really recommended.

I wanna know two things

> 1. How I can test my regex in windows subsystem for Linux.
> 2. how I can add it in the shell script, as of now I am using jq.

This is how I am using jq to fetch data in shell script

```
cat abc.json  | jq -r '.url'
```

So how i can achieve the same thing using regex ?

my abc.json is as below

```
{"url":"http://www.netcharles.com/orwell/essays.htm",
"domain":"netcharles.com",
"title":"Orwell Essays & Journalism Section - Charles' George Orwell Links",
"tags":["orwell","writing","literature","journalism","essays","politics","essay","reference","language","toread"],
"index":2931,
"time_created":1345419323,
"num_saves":24}
```

I tried this in windows subsystem for linux

> sed -E '(url|title|tags)":"((\"|[^"])*)' abc.json

got this error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `('

Expected output

```
\\"url\\":\\"http://www.netcharles.com/orwell/essays.htm\\",\\"domain\\":\\"netcharles.com\\",\\"title\\":\\"Orwell Essays & Journalism Section - Charles\\' George Orwell Links\\",\\"tags\\":[\\"orwell\\",\\"writing\\",\\"literature\\",\\"journalism\\",\\"essays\\",\\"politics\\",\\"essay\\",\\"reference\\",\\"language\\",\\"toread\\"],\\"index\\":2931,\\"time_created\\":1345419323,\\"num_saves\\":24
```

or could someone please tell me what would be regex for accessing something like this. ps -  the value of first_name will be a string

> cat user.json  | jq -r '.user_data.username.first_name'

Comment: @anubhava I tried this sed -E '(url|title|tags)":"((\\"|[^"])*)' abc.json , getting sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `('

Comment: So your expected output is almost full json document with some excessive quote escaping?

Comment: @anubhava No, this is just an example, I just want to know how I can fetch a value. even just value of one of the keys will work.

Comment: Why on earth is regex a requirement? It's been repeated here countless times already that trying to parse JSON or XML with regex is a really BAD idea! Use the right tools for the job.